# Liquid tag for custom linking

Tags: html, module, tags, jekyll, liquid

I am starting to use Jekyll and Liquid and I have some trouble about it.

Suppose I want to do some Liquid tag inside Jekyll that makes links: when writing

`...and according to {% cite my_link %} we have that...`

then Jekyll searches the post whose `caption` (some YAML predefined information) is `my_link` and creates a link for it according to some style. To create this Liquid tag I suppose one has to start with something like

```
module Jekyll
   class Cite < Liquid::Tag
     def render(context)
        caption = ????????
        aux = site.posts | where: "lang", page.lang | where: "caption", "#{@caption}" | first
        return <a href="{{aux.cleanurl}}" class="{{aux.kind}}" title="{{aux.title}}"></a>
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('cite', Jekyll::Cite)
```

First of all I do not know how to assign `caption=my_link`, that is, to extract the second part of `{% cite my_link %}`. Once we get it, will this code work or is it wrong?

**Thank you very much for your help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First question "*how to assign caption=my_link*" ?

You can read  [Jekyll Tags plugins documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags), and more important, [Liquid Tag code](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/3-0-stable/lib/liquid/tag.rb#L17).

In this last reference, you will learn that the `initialize` method is, by default, making a `@markup` variable available for other methods. This variable contains parameters passed to your tag.

So, once in `render` method you already have a `@markup` variable containing the desired value. You can then do `caption = @markup`. Note that this is only true for one parameter tags. For multiple parameters, you will have to use regular expressions on `@markup` to sort the pieces.

### Second question : Will your code work ?

The answer is NO. Plugins are ruby code not Liquid.

Here's an example that can work :

```
module Jekyll
  class CiteTag < Liquid::Tag
    def render(context)

      # @markup is a Liquid token so, we convert it to string
      # then we remove spaces before and after
      caption = @markup.to_s.strip
      site = context.registers[:site]
      posts = site.collections['posts'].docs
      page = context.registers[:page]

      if defined? page['lang'] and !page['lang'].nil? then
        # if current page has a lang front matter varaible set (or a default)
        currentLang = page['lang']
      elsif defined? site.config['lang']
        # if no lang is defined in current page, fallback to site.lang
        currentLang = site.config['lang']
      else
        # if no site.lang is available we raise an error
        raise "No default 'lang' option defined in _config.yml"
      end

      # create a new array with posts selected on currentLang and caption variable
      selectedPosts = posts.select do |post|
        postLang = post.data['lang']
        postCaption = post.data['caption']
        sameLang = postLang == currentLang
        sameCaption = postCaption == caption
        sameLang and sameCaption
      end

      # select first post
      post = selectedPosts.first

      # print the link
      link = "<a href=\"#{site.baseurl}#{post.url}\" class=\"#{post.data['kind']}\" title=\"#{post.data['title']}\">#{post.data['title']}</a>"

    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('cite', Jekyll::CiteTag)
```

Note : you have to set a `lang` variable in `_config.yml`. eg : `lang: 'en'`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! However, I somehow get `/_plugins/cite.rb:9:in 'render': undefined method 'docs' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. Why this problem?

Comment: Jekyll version ? Can you share your code in a repository ?

Comment: jekyll 2.5.3. Perhaps it is undefined in this version?

Comment: Ho ! You're running an old version. You'd better go with bundler and github pages ([see instructions here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/)). Otherwise, for jekyll 2.4+, you have to do `posts = site.posts` instead of `posts = site.collections['posts'].docs`.